# key hierarchy management and master key

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, key-management, key-generation, key-exchange

Now, I have this equation, `{{K_ab}K_bs}K_as`. `K_ab` is encrypted by `K_bs` then whole packet is encrypted by `K_as`

I think the key structure is `K_as` is the master key, `K_bs` is under `K_as` and `K_ab` is the session

My question is "If i have 2 long term keys and 1 session key, can i make both long term keys to be master key? Or only 1 out of 2 of them can be master key."